# Android App crash when I use an external url

Tags: android, angular, api, url

I have an angular App and in my App, I use an external URL from the company "Elfsight".
The external URL gives me an Instagram Feed that I can add photos to.
The App is working great when I use my PC, but when I try to use the App on my Android phone at some point it crashes.
I do some testing and when I remove the external URL the App is working great even n my Android phone.
Is there a solution for this, that I can use my Android to run the App and see the Instagram feed so it won't crash?
Thanks for the help!
Hezi

Comment: can you share some error logs ???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) permission to your manifest file.

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml
You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I have created the file "AndroidManifest.xml" and add the line :

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
outside the application tag but it still dont working.
I mean when I move to other page in my Android App it crash.
What am I missing here ?
Thanks,